# Is it possible to reconfigure App configuration after "CreateDefaultBuilder" call

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

In `CreateDefaultBuilder` a call is made to `ConfigureAppConfiguration` with some defaults. I'd like to override (or append) to these defaults. I've tried copying `CreateDefaultBuilder` into my own function and editing the appropriate lines, however it can't resolve a type used in the function because the type is `internal` to AspNetCore namespaces (specifically the `HostFilteringStartupFilter` type).

Is there some cleaner way for me to modify the `CreateDefaultBuilder` functionality?

EDIT: So I just looked at the source of `HostFilteringStartupFilter` and it just calls `UseHostFiltering` on the `IApplicationBuilder`, so I just added that to my `Startup.Configure` but I would still like a cleaner approach if possible..

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Overriding the defaults are pretty much well documented

Comment: Obviously I failed to properly fill out this question as I don't recall the specifics of what I was trying to achieve @Marcel. However for instance: https://github.com/aspnet/MetaPackages/blob/4738b4c26a24d2034b9ae1fe1b1d2f46ff858eec/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore/WebHost.cs#L148 the default builder sets up it's own logging, what if that interfered with my own logging? How would I go about disabling this? Also I have failed to locate any documentation on overriding `CreateDefaultBuilder` functionality, perhaps you can point me in the right direction?

Comment: Just scroll through this page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-2.1 and you will see how to customize logging. You can even remove the CreateDefaultBuild() call and add everything you need yourself.

Comment: @Marcel thanks for sharing that source, and while it is very informative I have not found a way to achieve what I wanted. On a basic level I wanted to start with `CreateDefaultBuilder` and then remove/add things until it worked as I desired. Your suggestion that I remove the `CreateDefaultBuilder` and just add everything and remove whatever I don't need is essentially what I did, but I was hoping for a cleaner solution. It seems like such a solution does not exist.

Answer (score 2):

CreateDefaultBuilder sets up reasonable defaults that you want to preserve except the configuration part.
CreateDefaultBuilder performs the following configuration setup:

1. appsettings.json
2. appsettings.{Environment}.json
3. Secret Manager (if Development environment)
4. Environment variables.
5. Command-line arguments.

Knowing this default layering, the fact that every layer can potentially override values in previous ones and the fact that you can only add configuration providers to the list (while not being able to remove them), you can now solve your problem.

Overriding configuration on top of CreateDefaultBuilder is done using ConfigureAppConfiguration :

```
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
        {
            // Override here specifying new or previous layers to make sure 
            // you get the desired outcome.
            // e.g. If you specify your appsettings.json you basically start from scratch
            ...

        })...
```